# In Google Play, it says "You need to upload an APK or Android App Bundle for this application"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

[image]

[image]

I'm on the review summary after my apk was uploaded. It says,

```
Errors
Resolve these errors before starting the roll-out of this release.

You need to upload an APK or Android App Bundle for this application.
You cannot remove all production APKs and Android App Bundles.
```

I've looked at various sources and am not sure what the solution is.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the first screenshot you are deactivating your first APK (version code 1). But you haven't uploaded a new version of your APK. You can't do a release without any APKs live. You have two choices:

- reactivate your old APK (Press the "Retain" (Now it is renamed to **Include**) button by the version 1 APK)
- upload a new APK

I assume you know what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a code version issue. update the code version 1 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

check into your manifest file:

```
android:versionCode="8"
```

and increase it,
that was the problem by me.

Answer (score 0):

Just discard the earlier release and add new one, the issue would be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Oh man! you are adding a second release or second version of the android app see your screenshot it says apks to be deactivated ..

see in that image actually you are deactivating the earlier version so just go to above button BROWSE FILES
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNF1C.png
Click BROWSE FILES and then select your apk file....

Now make sure that you are selecting a version 2 apk i mean not the same which you are deactivating that was version 1 or earlier version

You need to upload an APK or Android App Bundle for this application.
You cannot remove all production APKs and Android App Bundles.

It means that you have not selecteed any apk till now so just click BROWSE FILES and select apk file and you have to change the version also because you are adding a another version

look closely at your image 
and for changing the version go to 
Build gradle file of your app and see the version number you have to increment that by 1 or any positive quantity... increment only the version no decrement 
see Version written there  Version name "1.0"   change it to "2.0" and versioncode 1 to 2

because now playstore wont accept your earlier version apk i.e 1 it wil  only accept incremented version like 2 3 or 4 etc

Answer (score -3):

I figured out the problem (and yes I activated the APK beforehand as well). I didn't change the package name entirely in my .xml file. Once I did, I rebuilt my APK and it worked.

Comment: " my .xml file " what file you mean exactly? please explain more as others need a solution too.